# Deep learning based Resume Parser and Scoring

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, ai

I want to know if Deep learning can be used for Resume Parsing and scoring of the resume.

Currently what I am doing is extracting the text from pdf or image using OCR/tesseract and finding the features like Email, Mobile No, Skills, Tenure, No of Companies, Awards etc from the text. So I have close to 100 features which are important for scoring the resume.

Can we do similar thing using Deep learning and will the accuracy be better ?
Any starting point/document/blog/github link which can help me get started on this.

I have gone through [this link](https://medium.com/skillate/smart-recruitment-cracking-resume-parsing-through-deep-learning-part-i-dc37c655f30f) but this doesn't not have code to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Resume parsing and scoring can be done by identifying relevant keyword in the text. NER (Named Entity Recognition) is a technique to identify relevant keywords in text. There are different framework available to work with NER and NLP as a whole. I will suggest you to look into [spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/training/)

to train a custom NER model.